# What is being declared here? How does it look like after being declared?

Tags: javascript

I can't understand what the code after the dot means? How does the `scene` constant look like? Usually, we have declared a new instance of class like `let e = new E()`, but what is this?

```
const scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({x:12,y:12});
```

Comment: the ScrollMagic is a just a plaine object containing Class inside:
```ScrollMagic={Scene: function () {}, Car: function (){}}```

So to build an instance basing on these classes you write the way you've given and example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `new` keyword is used with a value.

It doesn't matter how you get that value. It just matters that it is a function.

`new Foo` gets the value from a variable called `Foo`.

`new Foo.Bar` gets the value from a *property* called `Bar` of an object which is got from a variable called `Foo`.

```js
const Foo = {
    Bar: function () { console.log("Hello"); }
}

new Foo.Bar();
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, `ScrollMagic` is a regular Javascript object with a property called `Scene`, which is a constructor for the class that gets instantiated here. So it could have been created like this:

```
const ScrollMagic = {
     Scene: function(position) {
         //constructor stuff happens here
     }
};
```

The dot is just the regular property accessor in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

ScrollMagic is a module. It contains a class Scene. So you can rewrite your code like this:

```
const Scene = ScrollMagic.Scene;

const scene = new Scene({x:12,y:12});
```

It is the same

Answer (score 0):

ScrollMagic seems to be a class which has a static method Scene, which returns an object.

Have a look at this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes